Which input/from colorspace should I specify if I want to "manually" apply Filmic or AgX in the compositor?
I saw CG Cookie's explanation of the limitations of "vanilla" AgX and I want to try out some pre-transform color correction. The "convert colorspace" node doesn't have an input for "raw," though.
If I pick "raw" in my color management, what input/from colorspace should I choose in the convert colorspace node?

I'm not at a PC right now so I cannot check, but if I remember correctly the node should have a Linear input, choose that because raw is linear information.

I understand very little about colorspaces, but from the comment of @GordonBrinkmann and a bit of testing, convert colorspace set from Linear CIE-XYZ E to AgX Base sRGB and raw view transform, seems identical to AgX view transform.

Thanks guys! It looks like Linear Rec.709 to AgX sRGB is the right combination, though Linear Rec.2020 to AgX Base Rec.2020 also looks identical? This gets me closer for now, but I'll need to look more closely at what these color spaces are like and when I want to use one over the other.
